# Web Socket Routing and the Improved Heroku Router

Tags: heroku, websocket, socket.io

In order to scale a websocket framework you usually have to employ some kind of load balancing in order to ensure each client stays connect to the same server [(such as socket.io)](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/). Does the new ["heroku improved router"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-improved-router) require this type of loading balancing? Or will web sockets keep a connection to the same server?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant documentation for websockets on Heroku is at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets

You can see the requirements relative to load-balancing in [Application Architecture](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets#application-architecture), where it is recommended not to rely on sticky sessions, but to rather use a back-end system that can allow the state to be made available to more instances.

The sticky session approach would tend to work very poorly on a platform such as Heroku where dynos and back-end instances can be moved, restarted, or stopped at least once a day; every instance of these would look like a netsplit and would leave your applications in a possibly undesirable state.

Comment: Your comment is about sharing application state across servers. That is not what I care about. I am wondering if Heroku's routing layer will automatically route websocket requests associated with a particular ip to the same server.

Comment: I'm telling you it doesn't work, and explaining why.